# Rails Arrays, Database and Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am creating an application that allows for users to create or join a team. A team has an array of skills, an array of categories, and an array of members. The problem I'm having is whenever I save to the database, it does not save as an array. I'm populating the cats field with choices based on the Cat model. I have another project where I made an array column and if I rails console Model_name.find(1) it will display the attribute with "---[]" denoting that it is an array. I can not figure out why this new application does not care about the fact that it's an array(because according to the output, it isn't, but according to migrations it is). I've been searching for this for about 3 days now to no avail. Just the same "solutions" that work for everyone but me.

```
--- controller -------

class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_team, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /teams
  # GET /teams.json
  def index
   @teams = Team.all
  end

  # GET /teams/1
  # GET /teams/1.json
  def show
    @owner = User.find(@team.user_id)
    @member = User.new
    @members = User.where(team_id: @team.id).where.not(team_role: "owner")
    @cats = []
  end

  # GET /teams/new
  def new
    @team = Team.new
  end

  # GET /teams/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /teams
  # POST /teams.json
  def create
    @team = Team.new(team_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @team.save
        user = User.find(@team.user_id)
        user.team_id = @team.id
        user.team_role = "owner"
        user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @team, success: 'Team was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @team }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /teams/1
  # PATCH/PUT /teams/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @team.update(team_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @team, success: 'Team was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @team }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /teams/1
  # DELETE /teams/1.json
  def destroy
    @team.destroy
    @users = User.where(team_id: @team.id)
    @users.each do |u|
      u.team_id = nil
      u.team_role = nil
      u.save
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to teams_url, notice: 'Team was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_team
      @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:name, :hiring, :user_id, :skills, :cats, :members, :tokens)
    end

end
```

---

```
--- model ------
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@team) do |f| %>    
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :hiring %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :hiring %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cats, "Select a Primary Category" %><br>
    <%= f.select :cats, Cat.all.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id]},{},{ class: 'form-control'} %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should do user.team = @team instead of adding the id, hopefully you added references when creating the models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `serialize` in order for `rails` to serialize/unserialize them.

First you need to ensure that the `column_type` of those fields is `text` in the database.

Then `serialize` those fields.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  serialize :cats, Array
end
```

Refer to [ActiveRecord.serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) for more info.